# File in Upload control not persisting on Submit button in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Recently, I was asked this question:

> When using a file upload control in ASP.Net MVC, why is the selected file not persisting on Submit button click? It does shows up in control when user selects it from hard drive. Other controls of that form are persisting on submit button click, but not this file upload control.

I replied it had got to with Ajax. I am new to Web technologies. Was my answer correct?

Comment: can you provide your code here?

Comment: @Bellash, thanks. This was an interview question asked orally to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears, I need to place the file upload control outside of UpdatePanel of Ajax, remaining controls like textboxes, button can go inside UpdatePanel so that their validation takes place. Another option would be to use hidden field for preserving the file value